# Google Apps Script - find string and return the following characters

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

The output in the log should be " scripting" because these are the next 10 characters followed by the search criteria "general-purpose". Please visit www.php.net to see what I mean, you will find the search string "general-purpose" on top of www.php.net. I think that I have done some more mistakes in this piece of code, right?

```
function parse() {
  // parse site and store html in response 
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('www.php.net').getContentText();
   // declare search string and new regex object
   var str = "/general-purpose/+10-following-charcters";
   var regExp = new RegExp("/general-purpose/.{0,10}", "gi");
   // find the string "general-purpose" and store the next 10 characters in response
   var response = regExp.exec(str[0]);
  // expected result in logger output is " scripting"
   Logger.log(response);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, there are some mistakes. Use `var regExp = new RegExp("/general-purpose/(.{0,10})", "i");`, then `var response = regExp.exec(str)[1];`. However, the first `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('www.php.net').getContentText();` text should be used, not `str`, and name variables differently.

Comment: Ok, thanx for your help, I'll check your suggestions in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `general-purpose(.{0,10})` and not `/general-purpose/.{0,10}`.
Also `regExp.exec(str[0])` should be `regExp.exec(str)[1]`.
This code seems to work fine

```
var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch('www.php.net').getContentText();
var regExp = new RegExp("general-purpose(.{0,10})", "gi");
var response = regExp.exec(str)[1];
Logger.log(response);
```